# Partitioning dual boot

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

Another day another question. :)

I've been trying eOS for the last couple of days on a external hdd. I very much like what I see. Because of that, I want to move from ubuntu to eOS. For that, I was checking the partitioning of my 2 harddrives. I found strange things and I am curious which I can remove. In the picture you find the output of lsblk:
[image: lsblk output]

sda is my classic 1Tb hdd. It contains a data partition which is shared by windows and linux. At also has the home parition of ubuntu. That one will be removed for eOS as I will be working with softlinks to the data partition. It also contains a curious BIOS_RVY partition. After some searching it seams to be a partition containing the factory defaults of msi. Can i delete it if I make a image as backup? I don't feel like losing 20Gb to some factory defaults. It also contains a 4th partition wich I can't seem to mount. When trying I get something that basically says "we have no idea what went wrong. Maybe you get some hints in the syslog." that however doesn't seem to contain anything useful.

Next drive, sdb, is my ssd. First partition is named WinRE tools. I have no clue about what it is or contains. Anybody got some hints? sdb2 is a /boot/efi parition so that one stays. Next up is some kind of mysterious microsoft reserved partition. That one should contain boot files etc for windows. So I believe that has to stay. As does the next, which contains my wind

Answer (score 1):

plz reformat the external after doing all of this , the drive is a mess, 
Looks like your computer is new, the other partitions are important for windows so don't touch them, and guess what ,if you remove the 20GB partition from your OEM you loose your chance to restore Windows and the licence is something that you might want to save, all the files that are in that partition is just for recovery if windows is damaged, so don't erase it.

first of all, make a backup of all..
then enter to windows and (press [windows key] + S) search "Disk manager" then you will se a lot of ... blue blocks, every block represent a partition, just delete ubuntu and the swap file(you will notice that easily because of sizes), and be sure that the block turns Black(only works if its black), if its green erease it again and it will turn black.

after reboot you will se a grub error or something, dont be scared is just some rubish that persists in your disk because of ubuntu's grub, insert the media/pendrive, reboot and press F12 as fast as posible when you look the OEM laptop's logo.

install elementary as always, then where finished you're able to dualboot windows and eos.

Comment: Which drive do you mean with external? Both drives are in my laptop. But I suspect you mean the 1Tb drive as 120Gb is rather small for an external HDD these days.

Comment: @Sander you said... _I've been trying eOS for the last couple of days on a external hdd_, I was talking about that external HDD

Comment: Aaah, but that one isn't listed on the image. On the external hard drive are only three partitions. One doe grub/boot, one for eOS and a swap partition. It is fairy clean and I intend tot use it as a portable customized os.

Comment: @Sander is just an advice, it doesn't have anything to do with I'm saying